# Multihop routing with Bird

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I want to route 192.168.117.0/24 via 192.168.12.117.

Host 192.168.12.117 connected with two links

```
192.168.12.117 dev ppp12
192.168.12.117 dev ppp0
```

I prefer BIRD for dynamic routing. I want to bird add multihop route like

```
ip route add  192.168.117.0/24 nexthop via 192.168.12.117 dev ppp0 nexthop via 192.168.12.117 dev ppp12
```

and add/change nexthops while new links established.

How can I configure it?

I have some routers with OSPF/RIP, but some routers without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Bird documentation](https://bird.network.cz/?get_doc&v=20&f=bird-6.html#ss6.14). The syntax of static routes is similar to that of iproute2:

```
protocol static {
    ipv4;

    route 192.168.117.0/24 via 192.168.12.117 % 'ppp0'
                           via 192.168.12.117 % 'ppp12';
}
```

To add new nexthops, just edit bird.conf and reload. Note that Bird will automatically update the kernel route whenever interfaces come up or down.

Bird 2 automatically generates multipath routes for OSPF – as long as there are multiple paths with identical costs, you will automatically see a route with multiple nexthops. (In Bird 1 you had to configure `ecmp on` within each OSPF protocol; this is now the default.)

```
# birdc show route protocol ospf4
10.147.1.3/32        unicast [ospf4 2021-05-30] * I (150/8) [193.219.181.229]
    via 10.147.240.3 on gre-xxx weight 1
    via 10.147.240.4 on gre-yyy weight 1
```

Finally, if you want Bird to add multipath routes using gateways from different protocols (e.g. a mix of static and OSPF gateways), you will need `merge paths` option for the kernel protocol:

```
protocol kernel {
    ipv4 { ... };
    merge paths on;
};
```

Without this option, only one "best" route is exported – it may still be a multipath route (e.g. if OSPF finds two equal-cost paths), but it will only come from one protocol.